# Can postgres delete constraint affect performance when doing SELECT, not delete?

Tags: postgresql, database, sql

For example, if I set ON DELETE CASCADE, can it somehow affect performance outside delete command? Or will it only affect performance when deleting?

And more importantly - if I set to do nothing on delete (eg no delete constraint), will postgres do any special validations when selecting from that table that could impact performance, or am I only risking getting corrupted data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely won't affect `SELECT`.

It can affect `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on the parent (referenced) table, and `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on the referencing side.

`DO NOTHING` doesn't mean "ignore this constraint". It's enforced. See the manual. The spelling is SQL-standard weirdness.